# Space commerce empire based on "better than chocolate" foodstuff

Tags: story-identification, food

I believe this was a series of books from the '70s and/or '80s.  The protagonist's family's wealth was based on their exclusive control of a foodstuff that was "better than chocolate".  I think the name of it started with a v, and that it was a fungus that could only be grown on a world they owned.  Who recalls it?

Comment: This feels as though it should be easy to find, but that is not proving to be the case. I'm pretty sure none of the novels in my library have a fungal food "better than chocolate" and Google is not helping.

Comment: Sure it was a fungus? John Ringo did something similar with Maple Syrup

Comment: @Paulie_D I noticed that too, but Ringo's work is at least 20 years too late...

Comment: An outside chance is the CHON chow from _[Beyond the Blue Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Blue_Event_Horizon)_, and the other sequels to _Gateway_. Robinette Broadhead becomes the richest man in the Solar System from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*Perseus Spur*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/378415.Perseus_Spur), the first book from The Rampart Worlds trilogy by Julian May. The substance is referred to as '*rozkoz*'.

> But Galapharma had unaccountably missed **rozkoz** when they combed
> Seriphos, so the confection more delicious than chocolate had founded
> the fortunes of the Frost family!

and

> Then I said, "You damn drunken fools! Don't you know what this is?"
>
> Gunter Eckert said, "**Better than chocolate**, for sure."
>
> "It's our jackpot!" I told them. "The gravy train! The big break!"

Comment: Can you give some insight into how this book matches the description?

Comment: Interesting failure of Google books.  You can't find this by searching for "better than chocolate" even though that exact string appears in the book, and that part of the book is in the Google books preview.  It's a 1998 title though, so it might be a bit late for 70s/80s.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why my answer was completely rewritten like someone rewriting something for a book report.  I did buy the book on Kindle after searching for interstellar commerce/food and verified the passage.